# Remember me/stay logged in, in jsp login page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, authentication, remember-me

I have a login screen and i want to authenticate users by checking credentials from database. I know most browsers can remember the password, but how can i implement Remember me check box by using the browser cookies? I am using sign.jsp and Auth servlet (doPost) and basic access authentication with https.

I know I need to store the userid + token into cookies. I found the following codes from another thread.

In your servlet response handler (doPost, doGet etc.) create a cookie in the following way -

```
if(remember_me_is_checked)
{
    Cookie c = new Cookie("userid", userId.toString());
    c.setMaxAge(24*60*60);
    response.addCookie(c);  // response is an instance of type HttpServletReponse
}
```

To read them, you can use something like this -

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();     // request is an instance of type 
                                             //HttpServletRequest
boolean foundCookie = false;

for(int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
{ 
    Cookie c = cookies[i];
    if (c.getName().equals("userid"))
    {
        string userId= c.getValue();
        foundCookie = true;
    }
}
```

My question is, after I store user info into cookies, how can I sign the user in automatically when the user logs in next time? What I dont understand is that I only have user's login id stored in cookies, how could I sign the user in without password. What method could I use?

Please explain or provide some codes specifically if possible. I am really new to this kind of stuff.

Best Regards

Comment: What do you mean by, " i do NOT want to authenticate users by checking credentials from database" ?

Comment: more specifically, what method can I use to logged in the users if the userid and/or password match the ones in my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we store *token* - a status information to determine whether as user is logged or not, into the cookies. (Do not store password and other credential in cookies).

I'd like to suggest you to use `filter`. In doFilter() method read cookies and based upon cookie's value or availability of cookie you may authenticate a request.

Comment: your suggestion is very good. But how do I sign in the users after authenticate successfully. I don't store their password. I just store the userid and token, cookie's value or something like that but not password. What method could I use to sign them in automatically. I am using container based form authentication. I think I can sigh them in if I stored their password by automatically submit what userid and password that I stored in DataBase. What if I don't store their password, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to store only userid in the cookie. The simplest solution I see is to store some sort of password hash along with the userid.

Take userid + some_secret_string + password.

Calculate the hash function out of it.

Push the userid and computed hash to the cookie.

When the user returns you'll get 2 strings.

Based on the userid you'll get the password from your database.

Calculate the hash function again.

Compare the calculated hash with the one from the cookie.

If they match - user is logged in again.